# Classify unnest elements in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, date, unnest

I'm using `PostgreSQL` 10.6 and i want to read a table with an array of dates. My goal is to classify each date in this array and compare it to the date of the day, to affect them a  category : past, present, futur.

With a case statment i've already classify records depending of their values and in the other hand i'm able to unnest elements from this array. But when i try a case statement in unnest elements, response isn't what i'm expecting.

**myTable**

```
id(integer) | dates(date[])
---------------------------
1           | {2020-03-17}
2           | {2020-03-17,2020-03-16}
3           | {2020-03-16,2020-03-15}
4           | {2020-03-17,2020-03-18}
5           | {2020-03-16,2020-03-18}
```

An simple query return me each date in a distinct row

```
SELECT id, UNNEST(dates) FROM myTable
```

An other query return me a result by not a good one, because some dates in the past are displayed "Futur" for example.

```
SELECT
    id,
    UNNEST(dates),
    CASE
        WHEN dates < ARRAY[now()::date] THEN 'Past'
        WHEN dates = ARRAY[now()::date] THEN 'Present'
        WHEN dates > ARRAY[now()::date] THEN 'Futur'
    END AS myResult
FROM myTable
ORDER BY UNNEST(dates) DESC
```

How can i succeed to this result ? I think i'm missing something important.

```
id |     dates     |   myResult
--------------------------------
4  | {2020-03-18}  |   Futur
5  | {2020-03-18}  |   Futur
1  | {2020-03-17}  |   Present
2  | {2020-03-17}  |   Present
4  | {2020-03-17}  |   Present
2  | {2020-03-16}  |   Past
3  | {2020-03-16}  |   Past
5  | {2020-03-16}  |   Past
3  | {2020-03-15}  |   Past
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unnest in the `from` clause - then you can classify in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    d.dt,
    CASE
        WHEN d.dt < current_date THEN 'Past'
        WHEN d.dt = current_date THEN 'Present'
        WHEN d.dt > current_date THEN 'Futur'
    END AS myResult
FROM myTable t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(t.dates) d(dt)
ORDER BY t.id, d.dt DESC
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b92478b377e168bb0bbea23000263506)**:

```
id | dt         | myresult
-: | :--------- | :-------
 1 | 2020-03-17 | Present
 2 | 2020-03-17 | Present
 2 | 2020-03-16 | Past
 3 | 2020-03-16 | Past
 3 | 2020-03-15 | Past
 4 | 2020-03-18 | Futur
 4 | 2020-03-17 | Present
 5 | 2020-03-18 | Futur
 5 | 2020-03-16 | Past
```

Comment: Great ! I'm not used to `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`. I will read some docs about it. A big thanks.